# How to transform file from python to html or javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax

I am creating a UI. My back end code is in python. Python handlers are called by the javascript(using ajax). I am creating a csv file using python like below.

```
Results = []
filename = "D:/mydir/testing.csv"
csvfilename = "D:/mydir/testing.csv"
Results.append(["test1","test2","test3"])
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(Results)
csvfile = open(csvfilename, "r")
self.set_header("Content-Type", "application/csv")   
self.set_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="testing.csv"')
tempfile = csvfile.read()
self.write(tempfile)
```

Above code is creating file(with type 'Microsoft Office Excel Comma Separated Values File (.csv)').I am calling above handler on click using ajax call like below.

```
$.get("/filehandler", {startdate:startdate,enddate:enddate,reportname:reportname},function(data)
{
    alert(data);
});
```

Actually my intention is on click over button it should ask for saving 'testing.csv' file.
Now i have hard coded array contents, the data for the file should come from python.
Is there any way to get solution using below code ?

```
<a onclick="function()" download>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can link to the script directly:

```
<a href="path-to-your-hardcoded-python-script">download</a>
```

In response to you comment, there is no need to use an Ajax call because the parameters are already hard coded. Opening the above link *will* trigger a download, because the python script already has the download headers set.

Comment: I have to use ajax call for python handlers. ajax response should be downloadable file